# Convert JArray to list, keeping only one nested JToken

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a JArray that looks like this:

```json
[
    {
        "1": "A",
        "2": "B",
        "3": {
            "5": "D",
            "KeyICareAbout": "C"
        }
    },
    {
        "1": "E",
        "2": "F",
        "3": {
            "5": "H",
            "KeyICareAbout": "G"
        }
    }
]
```

I only care about the value of `KeyICareAbout`. How can I remove all other tokens and convert the array into a list? The array might be big, so I don't think looping would be efficient. I'm currently doing it this way, but it feels very convoluted and brittle. I feel like I'm overlooking an easy solution

```
//flattens the JArray by keeping only the values and converts it to Lookup. Uses the last element of the path as the key.
var lookup = array.Descendants().OfType<JValue>().ToLookup(jv => jv.Path.Substring(jv.Path.LastIndexOf(".")+1), jv => jv.Value) 

//converts lookup to list
var list = lookup["KeyICareAbout"].ToList()
```

Comment: If you're concerned about memory consumption, one thing is to avoid premature materialization by removing excess calls to `ToList` and `ToLookup`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can improve the efficiency of your code as follows:

```
var key = "KeyICareAbout";
var list = array.Descendants()
    .OfType<JProperty>() // Look for all properties
    .Where(p => p.Name == key) // With the name KeyICareAbout
    .Select(p => p.Value) // And select their value.
    .ToList();
```

Notes:

- [`ToLookup()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup) builds a hashed lookup table for all keys encountered in the JSON, which should be roughly `n log(n) * k` with `n` the number of unique keys and `k` the average number of values per key.  You only care about the value of one specific key, so you'll get better performance by filtering out irrelevant keys with a `Where()` expression and skipping creation of the lookup table entirely.

  If you need to your result JSON to contain the values of many keys, a lookup table would make sense.
- Rather than parsing the `Path` string, you can just get the property name from the immediate parent `JProperty` of the values you want.

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DJ1pn8).

In your question you state *The array might be big*.  If the JSON is extremely large (many MB in size) you might want to adopt a streaming solution and only load the values of `"KeyICareAbout"` into memory.  The following does that:

```
var key = "KeyICareAbout";

using var stream = File.OpenRead(fileName);
using var textReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
using var reader = new JsonTextReader(textReader);

var list = new List<JToken>();
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName && (string)reader.Value == key)
    {
        list.Add(JToken.Load(reader.ReadToContentAndAssert()));
    }
}
```

Using extension methods from:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader AssertTokenType(this JsonReader reader, JsonToken tokenType) => 
        reader.TokenType == tokenType ? reader : throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unexpected token {0}, expected {1}", reader.TokenType, tokenType));
    
    public static JsonReader ReadToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader) =>
        reader.ReadAndAssert().MoveToContentAndAssert();

    public static JsonReader MoveToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(reader);
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)       // Skip past beginning of stream.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment) // Skip past comments.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        return reader;
    }

    public static JsonReader ReadAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(reader);
        if (!reader.Read())
            throw new JsonReaderException("Unexpected end of JSON stream.");
        return reader;
    }
}
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NlGny4).

Comment: definitely an improvement! Upvoted.  I'll wait a bit before accepting